# Debug vs Release em CMake

Tags: debug, release, cmake

Como especificar as **flags** para **debug** vs release C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

[CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html) é a variável do CMake que você procura. Você pode gerar os arquivos do build passando a definição dessa variável por linha de comando:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..
```

Você também pode alterar o valor do `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` rodando `ccmake ..`, ativando o modo avançado (apertando a tecla <kbd>t</kbd>). Quando terminar, aperte <kbd>c</kbd> para configurar e <kbd>g</kbd> para gerar os novos arquivos.